# VBA - Find max value and fill its cell with a color

Tags: vba, loops

I want to find a day which has the maximum unit price in a month. As below, I can see maxval doesn't work outside of the Loop. Could you please advise on this?

```
Sub Test()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim ix As Long
    Dim maxnum As Long
    Dim maxval As Range

    maxnum = 0
    
    'Week Loop
    For i = 1 To 4
        ix = (i - 1) * 4 + 2
  
        'Weekday Loop
        For j = 3 To 9
        Set maxval = Cells(ix + 3, j)
        
            If maxval.Value > maxnum Then
            maxnum = maxval.Value
            End If

        Next j
    
    Next i
    
    If maxval.Value = maxnum Then
        maxval.Interior.Color = vbYellow
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. We'll need more information in order to help. What exactly is the problem & what do you need to do? Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make maxnum a range object so you can reference it after the loop.

Something like this:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim ix As Long
    Dim maxnum As Range
    Dim maxval As Range
    
    'Week Loop
    For i = 1 To 4
        ix = (i - 1) * 4 + 5 ' I made this plus 5 because you were adding 3 to it later on.
        'Weekday Loop
        For j = 3 To 9
        Set maxval = Cells(ix, j)
        
            If maxnum Is Nothing Then 'Avoid an unset object error
                Set maxnum = maxval
            ElseIf maxval.Value > maxnum.Value Then
                Set maxnum = maxval
            End If

        Next j
    
    Next i
    
    maxnum.Interior.Color = vbYellow 'Changed this to maxnum instead of maxval

End Sub
```

Comment: Changed it to plus 5 also, now it works, thank you!